# OpenSSL build script fails when run as a 'run script' phase within Xcode (succeeds outside of Xcode)

Tags: iphone, xcode, bash, openssl, build-script

I'm attempting to run a script to build OpenSSL for iOS (armv6, armv7 and i386) as a 'run script' phase in Xcode.

The script builds successfully when run from the command line as a stand alone script. The result is a compiled `libcrypto.a`, `libssl.a` and `include` directory with the headers.

However, when I run the script as a run script phase in Xcode, it gets towards the end of make and errors out stating that it couldn't find any symbols referenced from libcrypto.

```
shlib_target=; if [ -n "" ]; then \
        shlib_target="bsd-gcc-shared"; \
    fi; \
    LIBRARIES="-L.. -lssl  -L.. -lcrypto" ; \
    make -f ../Makefile.shared -e \
        APPNAME=openssl OBJECTS="openssl.o verify.o asn1pars.o req.o dgst.o dh.o dhparam.o enc.o passwd.o gendh.o errstr.o ca.o pkcs7.o crl2p7.o crl.o rsa.o rsautl.o dsa.o dsaparam.o ec.o ecparam.o x509.o genrsa.o gendsa.o genpkey.o s_server.o s_client.o speed.o s_time.o apps.o s_cb.o s_socket.o app_rand.o version.o sess_id.o ciphers.o nseq.o pkcs12.o pkcs8.o pkey.o pkeyparam.o pkeyutl.o spkac.o smime.o cms.o rand.o engine.o ocsp.o prime.o ts.o" \
        LIBDEPS=" $LIBRARIES " \
        link_app.${shlib_target}
( :; LIBDEPS="${LIBDEPS:--L.. -lssl  -L.. -lcrypto }"; LDCMD="${LDCMD:-/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch i386}"; LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS:--isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -pthread -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DTERMIOS -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall}"; LIBPATH=`for x in $LIBDEPS; do echo $x; done | sed -e 's/^ *-L//;t' -e d | uniq`; LIBPATH=`echo $LIBPATH | sed -e 's/ /:/g'`; LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBPATH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LDCMD} ${LDFLAGS} -o ${APPNAME:=openssl} openssl.o verify.o asn1pars.o req.o dgst.o dh.o dhparam.o enc.o passwd.o gendh.o errstr.o ca.o pkcs7.o crl2p7.o crl.o rsa.o rsautl.o dsa.o dsaparam.o ec.o ecparam.o x509.o genrsa.o gendsa.o genpkey.o s_server.o s_client.o speed.o s_time.o apps.o s_cb.o s_socket.o app_rand.o version.o sess_id.o ciphers.o nseq.o pkcs12.o pkcs8.o pkey.o pkeyparam.o pkeyutl.o spkac.o smime.o cms.o rand.o engine.o ocsp.o prime.o ts.o ${LIBDEPS} )

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ENGINE_load_gost", referenced from:
      _ENGINE_load_builtin_engines in libcrypto.a(eng_all.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [link_app.] Error 1
make[1]: *** [openssl] Error 2
make: *** [build_apps] Error 1
```

I'm almost certain that this is a paths issue, but I can't figure out how to tell Xcode (or the script) which paths to use.

The script, [available here](http://www.x2on.de/2010/12/16/tutorial-script-for-building-openssl-for-ios-iphoneipad/), needed to be modified to account for the recent changes to the location of the developer tools with Xcode 4.3 (namely the fact that Developer/ is no longer at the root, but actually inside Xcode.app).

Here's the script for question completeness:

```
#!/bin/sh

#  Automatic build script for libssl and libcrypto 
#  for iPhoneOS and iPhoneSimulator
#
#  Created by Felix Schulze on 16.12.10.
#  Copyright 2010 Felix Schulze. All rights reserved.
#
#  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#  limitations under the License.
#
###########################################################################
#  Change values here                                                     #
#                                                                         #
VERSION="1.0.0c"                                                          #
SDKVERSION="5.0"                                                          #
#                                                                         #
###########################################################################
#                                                                         #
# Don't change anything under this line!                                  #
#                                                                         #
###########################################################################



CURRENTPATH=`pwd`
CURRENTPATH="${CURRENTPATH}/openssl"

set -e
if [ ! -e openssl-${VERSION}.tar.gz ]; then
echo "Downloading openssl-${VERSION}.tar.gz"
curl -O http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-${VERSION}.tar.gz
else
echo "Using openssl-${VERSION}.tar.gz"
fi

mkdir -p "${CURRENTPATH}/src"
tar zxf openssl-${VERSION}.tar.gz -C "${CURRENTPATH}/src"
rm openssl-${VERSION}.tar.gz
cd "${CURRENTPATH}/src/openssl-${VERSION}"


############
# iPhone Simulator
echo "Building openssl for iPhoneSimulator ${SDKVERSION} i386"
echo "Please stand by..."

export CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch i386"
mkdir -p "${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneSimulator${SDKVERSION}.sdk"

LOG="${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneSimulator${SDKVERSION}.sdk/build-openssl-${VERSION}.log"

./configure BSD-generic32 --openssldir="${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneSimulator${SDKVERSION}.sdk" > "${LOG}" 2>&1
# add -isysroot to CC=
sed -ie "s!^CFLAG=!CFLAG=-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator${SDKVERSION}.sdk !" "Makefile"

make >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
make install >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
make clean >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
#############

#############
# iPhoneOS armv6
echo "Building openssl for iPhoneOS ${SDKVERSION} armv6"
echo "Please stand by..."

export CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch armv6"
mkdir -p "${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneOS${SDKVERSION}-armv6.sdk"

LOG="${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneOS${SDKVERSION}-armv6.sdk/build-openssl-${VERSION}.log"

./configure BSD-generic32 --openssldir="${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneOS${SDKVERSION}-armv6.sdk" > "${LOG}" 2>&1

sed -ie "s!^CFLAG=!CFLAG=-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${SDKVERSION}.sdk !" "Makefile"
# remove sig_atomic for iPhoneOS
sed -ie "s!static volatile sig_atomic_t intr_signal;!static volatile intr_signal;!" "crypto/ui/ui_openssl.c"

make >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
make install >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
make clean >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
#############

#############
# iPhoneOS armv7
echo "Building openssl for iPhoneOS ${SDKVERSION} armv7"
echo "Please stand by..."

export CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch armv7"
mkdir -p "${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneOS${SDKVERSION}-armv7.sdk"

LOG="${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneOS${SDKVERSION}-armv7.sdk/build-openssl-${VERSION}.log"


./configure BSD-generic32 --openssldir="${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneOS${SDKVERSION}-armv7.sdk" >> "${LOG}" 2>&1

sed -ie "s!^CFLAG=!CFLAG=-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${SDKVERSION}.sdk !" "Makefile"
# remove sig_atomic for iPhoneOS
sed -ie "s!static volatile sig_atomic_t intr_signal;!static volatile intr_signal;!" "crypto/ui/ui_openssl.c"

make >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
make install >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
make clean >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
#############

echo "Build library..."
lipo -create ${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneSimulator${SDKVERSION}.sdk/lib/libssl.a ${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneOS${SDKVERSION}-armv6.sdk/lib/libssl.a ${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneOS${SDKVERSION}-armv7.sdk/lib/libssl.a -output ${CURRENTPATH}/libssl.a

lipo -create ${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneSimulator${SDKVERSION}.sdk/lib/libcrypto.a ${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneOS${SDKVERSION}-armv6.sdk/lib/libcrypto.a ${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneOS${SDKVERSION}-armv7.sdk/lib/libcrypto.a -output ${CURRENTPATH}/libcrypto.a

mkdir -p ${CURRENTPATH}/include
cp -R ${CURRENTPATH}/bin/iPhoneSimulator${SDKVERSION}.sdk/include/openssl ${CURRENTPATH}/include/
echo "Building done."
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is an older post, I think the problem still persist. But I think I found a very simple solution. Just add the following line to the Build-Script, before "Configure" or "make" is called:

```
export COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It's been logged as an issue on [openssl](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2236&user=guest&pass=guest).

Adjust your configure line:

```
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc zlib no-asm no-krb5 shared
```

Comment: That may work if you're building for 64 bit Mac OS X, but I'm attempting to build for iOS, (hence the need for armv6, armv7 and i386). I have to specify `BSD-generic32` as opposed to `darwin-x86_64` and iOS does not allow shared libraries either. I tried configure with my BSD and without the shared option, but I get the same error as I stated in the original question.